# How to use cummean based on a condition in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative mean of a column in my data frame, but I only want it to be done based on a condition.

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c("A","A","B","B","A"),
                   col2 = c(1,0,1,0,1))
```

Lets say I want to calculate `col3` as the `cummean` of `col2` but only if `col1 = "A"`

Expected output should be

```
A 1 1.00
A 1 0.50
B 1 NA
B 0 NA
A 1 0.67
```

Ideally it would be nice if the NA values picked up the `lag` value of cummean as a default. Something like

```
A 1 1.00
A 1 0.50
B 1 0.50
B 0 0.50
A 1 0.67
```

I was trying out `mutate_if` but couldn't quite work out the right syntax. Perhaps the answer should be `cummean` inside an `ifelse` with a regular `mutate`. Not sure what's the best way to approach. Any help hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the cumulative sum of `col2` conditionally and then divide by cumulative count of *A* in `col1`:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(cummean = { 
    isA <- col1 == 'A'
    cumsum(isA * col2) / cumsum(isA) 
  })

#  col1 col2   cummean
#1    A    1 1.0000000
#2    A    0 0.5000000
#3    B    1 0.5000000
#4    B    0 0.5000000
#5    A    1 0.6666667
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I found a solution myself

```
data %>%
  mutate(col3 = ifelse(col1 == A, cummean(col2), NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(col3, .direction = "up") ## for filling up the NA values with previous values
```

Any cleaner/better approaches?